# Javascript about array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Just wondering, why is it wrong for me to declare an array by filling it with objects like displayed on the bottom? And is the best way to do push? 
Also..is there a difference between doing var array=[] and declaring it with the "new" keyword? I'm trying to do console.log(moonlight.rating) and nothing shows up...not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
function Movie(title, rating, hasWatched)
{
this.title=title;
this.rating=rating;
this.hasWatched=hasWatched;
}

var la_la_land=Movie("La La Land", 8.6, true);
var moonlight=Movie("Moonlight", 8.1, false);
var fifty_shades=Movie("Fifty Shades Darker", -1, false);

var arrays=[la_la_land, moonlight, fifty_shades];
```

Comment: It's not wrong for you to do it like that - it's just one of the ways to populate an array - why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Maybe that wasn't the problem...I'm trying to do console.log(moonlight.rating) and it won't show up.

Comment: Well, that depends on your `Movie` class...

Comment: Okay, I put up my Movie constructor....do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with instantiating arrays. You have to use the `new` keyword for the `Movie` constructor:

```
var la_la_land= new Movie("La La Land", 8.6, true);
var moonlight= new Movie("Moonlight", 8.1, false);
var fifty_shades= new Movie("Fifty Shades Darker", -1, false);
```

Comment: Ohhh got it :')